# How to simplify a statement of lemma

Tags: coq

I have a Contradictory statements in hypothesis. Want to convert it into true=false. Thanks for guidence in advance. Here is code

```
  n < current_value 0  (n :: l)
  current_value 0  (n :: l)<= n.
```

Answer (score 1):

The question could be a lot more complete. What is the type of `n`? I'll assume that it is `nat`.

Starting like this:

```
Lemma manual:
  forall current_value n l P,
  n < current_value 0 (n :: l) ->
  current_value 0 (n :: l) <= n ->
  P.
Proof.
  intros.
```

We arrive at a state that looks like this (omitting things we don't need):

```
H : n < current_value 0 (n :: l)
H0 : current_value 0 (n :: l) ≤ n
-----
P
```

The strategy will be to prove that `H` and `H0` together lead to a contradiction from which we can prove any statement `P`.

We know that `n < m` (if `m` stands for the expression `current_value 0 (n :: l)`) and also `m <= n`. What can we prove from this? You can search for relevant lemmas using the `Search` command with a pattern that summarizes what you know:

```
  Search (?n < ?m -> ?m <= ?p -> _).
```

This query means "given that I know that `n < m` and also `m <= p` for the same `m`, what can I deduce?". The named variables in the query need the `?` prefix, they can stand for any expressions. They are *not* related to any variables you might have in the current environment.

One of the search hits is this (in `PeanoNat`, which you will have to import):

```
Nat.lt_le_trans:
forall n m p : nat, n < m -> m <= p -> n < p
```

So given this lemma we should be able to prove `n < n` and see if we can make progress from there.

```
  {
    apply Nat.lt_le_trans with (m := current_value 0 (n :: l)).
    auto.
    auto.
  }
```

Now we have:

```
H1 : n < n
-----
P
```

So now we have a more "obvious" contradiction in an assumption. Do we have a lemma for proving that this is indeed false?

```
  Search (~ ?n < ?n).
```

This gives:

```
Nat.lt_irrefl: forall x : nat, ~ x < x
```

So then:

```
  apply Nat.lt_irrefl in H1.
```

We arrive at:

```
H1 : False
-----
P
```

This is a tautology that we can prove with `tauto`:

```
  tauto.
Qed.
```

Doing such simple arithmetic manually can get very tedious, so there is a lot of automation for doing it. Here's a simpler method using the `lia` tactic:

```
Require Import Lia.

Lemma automatic:
  forall current_value n l P,
  n < current_value 0 (n :: l) ->
  current_value 0 (n :: l) <= n ->
  P.
Proof.
  intros.
  lia.
Qed.
```

Internally this will do some sort of similar reasoning, proving a contradiction in the assumptions.

Comment: when I execute ,Lemma automatic: Error message "In nested Ltac calls to "lia" and
"xlia (tactic)", last call failed.
In nested Ltac calls to "lia" and
"xlia (tactic)", last call failed.
Tactic failure: Bad logical fragment.". For Lemma manual:message is "Unable to unify "S ?M1402 <= ?M1404" with 
"P".". Secondly how I can close goal (0 <= a)  about natural number a ,while  I have hypothesis .((a =? 0) = false)

Comment: which version of coq are you using?  The script given above works with coq-8.12

Comment: In coq-8.11, it works too.  In coq-8.10, `lia` complains with your error message.  You have to replace `P` which `lia`does not know, with a constant that is stronger: `False`.  for instance with the following line `assert (abs : False) by lia; destruct abs.`

Comment: I am using Coq 8.8.0. I have replaced P with False.Still bad fragment message appears.